# Documentation about write /feed and Parameter in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am searching for a good documentation on how to use the parameters like "link", "picture" "description, caption and what is possible. I have read the official documentation about "post", but its only about, which param exists, but not, what to fill in it/which is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be looking for this

Method: /PROFILE_ID/feed
Description: Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall

Arguments: message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source

Its somewhere on this page, quite badly documented imho,
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I´ve already read this. Under Publishing is "more detailed information " and this is the explanation "Post" of wich I wrote above.

But its not possible to do it with every link and every pictures. This is, what i miss in their docu.

But I thank you for the answer , because no one anwsered here, exxcept you. I really regret, that facebook has locked their old Support forum, where more herp was avaiable sometimes.